# Why in TensorFlow implementations of metrics `tensorflow.python.ops.x` is used instead of `tf.x`

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am curious why in TF implementations of metrics (and probably everywhere else) `tensorflow.python.ops.x` are used instead of just `tf.x`, for example, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py#L791) `tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops.reduce_sum` is used instead of `tf.reduce_sum`.

Guess: is it done for efficiency, so that we don't need to do `import tensorflow as tf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Tensorflow reference page for your example (reduce_sum)
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum

you will see that you can use tf.math.reduce_sum or tf.reduce_sum interchangeably, as they are aliased to each other.

In the example page that you linked to, that was Tensorflow code within the  tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py module, and it was referencing code imported as

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
```

This is the best way for this code to reference code within its own tensorflow.python.ops module.  The tf.reduce_sum reference is the way to reference code from **outside** the tensorflow source code itself, as will be the case for most user code.  It is best to follow the documentation page references to better survive future code reorganizations, etc.